# Load Cocos3D Scene on a UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I want to load a Cocos3D Scene inside a `UIViewController`. Currently I have integrate Cocos3D in to my normal iOS project. How can I load Cocos3D scene on to RootViewController's view.

I found a way of using **EAGLView**. But I do not have a clue about EAGLView and CCDirector. Heres the code currently Im trying.
Is there any other way to do it? Please let me know

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    CCDirector * director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [self.view addSubview:[director openGLView]];
    cc3Layer = [LR3DLayer layerWithColor:ccc4(100, 100, 100, 255) width:768 height:960];
    [cc3Layer scheduleUpdate];
    world = [LR3DScene scene];
    cc3Layer.cc3Scene = world;
    scene = [CCScene node];
    [scene addChild: (ControllableCCLayer*)cc3Layer];
    if([director runningScene])
        [director replaceScene:scene];
    else
        [director runWithScene:scene];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the examples in the `AppDelegate` implementations in the **cocos3d** `CC3DemoMashUp` demo app, or the **cocos3d** *hello, world* template app.

**cocos3d** requires you to use a subclass of `CC3UIViewController`. The controller will automatically create and use the required `CC3GLView` view.